# Ranking Search Results With LINQ/.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a task where I need to rank the search results based on which column the search term was found.

So for example, if the search term is found in column A of table 1, it ranks higher than if it was found in column A of table 2.

Right now, I have a linq query that joins multiple tables and searches for the search term in certain columns.  I.E.

```
var results = db.People
    .Join(db.Menu, p => p.ID, m => m.PersonID, (p, m) => new { p = p, m = m })
    .Join(db.Domain, m => m.m.DomainID, d => d.ID, (m, d) => new { m = m, d = d })
    .Where(d => searchTermArray.Any(x => d.m.p.p.Name.Contains(x)) || searchTermArray.Any(x => d.m.p.p.Biography.Contains(x)) || searchTermArray.Any(x => d.d.domain.Contains(x)))
    .Select(p => p).Distinct();
```

So if the search term is found in db.People, column Name, that row/Person will rank higher than if found in db.People, column Biography, which will rank higher than if found in db.Domain, column domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will order your result by the "rank". You can manipulate the query further if you also want to return the rank and not only the aggregate:

```
var results = db.People
    .Join(db.Menu, p => p.ID, m => m.PersonID, (p, m) => new { p = p, m = m })
    .Join(db.Domain, m => m.m.DomainID, d => d.ID, (m, d) => new { m = m, d = d })
    .Select(d => new
            {
                rank = searchTermArray.Any(x => d.m.p.p.Name.Contains(x)) ? 3 : searchTermArray.Any(x => d.m.p.p.Biography.Contains(x)) ? 2 : searchTermArray.Any(x => d.d.domain.Contains(x)) ? 1 : 0,
                m = d
            })
    .Where(a => a.rank > 0)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.rank)
    .Select(a => a.m).Distinct();
```

Note: I take no responsibility for poor performance, that's LINQ after all.

Comment: How would I also return the rank?

Comment: remove the `.Select(a => a.m)` statement

Comment: But what if I want to only return specific columns, not all of them, from db.People?

Comment: This is another question, please remember that what you are asking is basic LINQ syntax. This is not the place for asking different questions.

Comment: Made a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639192/return-only-certain-columns

Comment: @yondaimehokage Please remember to mark the answer if it worked.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, so I cannot mark it as working yet.