# Return only certain columns

Tags: c#, linq

Since I was told I need to make a new question:

I have this query from this question ([Ranking Search Results With LINQ/.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596800/ranking-search-results-with-linq-net-mvc/43597400#43597400)):

```
var results = db.People
.Join(db.Menu, p => p.ID, m => m.PersonID, (p, m) => new { p = p, m = m })
.Join(db.Domain, m => m.m.DomainID, d => d.ID, (m, d) => new { m = m, d = d })
.Select(d => new
        {
            rank = searchTermArray.Any(x => d.m.p.p.Name.Contains(x)) ? 3 : searchTermArray.Any(x => d.m.p.p.Biography.Contains(x)) ? 2 : searchTermArray.Any(x => d.d.domain.Contains(x)) ? 1 : 0,
            m = d
        })
.Where(a => a.rank > 0)
.OrderByDescending(a => a.rank)
.Select(a => a.m).Distinct();
```

I need to return the rank and only certain columns from db.People.  How do I do that?

Comment: Define `certain columns`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do in your query, new {...} like :

```
    var results = db.People
   .Join(db.Menu, p => p.ID, m => m.PersonID, (p, m) => new { p = p, m = m })
   .Join(db.Domain, m => m.m.DomainID, d => d.ID, (m, d) => new { m = m, d = d })
   .Select(d => new
    {
        rank = searchTermArray.Any(x => d.m.p.p.Name.Contains(x)) ? 3 :    searchTermArray.Any(x => d.m.p.p.Biography.Contains(x)) ? 2 : searchTermArray.Any  (x => d.d.domain.Contains(x)) ? 1 : 0,
        m = d
    })
  .Where(a => a.rank > 0)
  .OrderByDescending(a => a.rank)
  .Select(a =>  new {
  column1 = a.column1, 
  column2 = a.column2
  ....
  }).Distinct();
```